# how to change the name of the tabcontrol

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am using a Tab Control in a C# WinForms application. I want to change the title of the tabs. By default they are tabPage1, tabPage2, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can change it pretty simply in the designer; click on a blank area in the tab page contents and use the property view to set the `Text` property.  Also through code via:

```
tabPage1.Text = @"Something Meaningful";
```

Where `tabPage1` would be the reference to whichever `TabPage` you wanted to set the `Text` of.

Answer (score 80):

## A lazy way to do it without code:

- Select the tab control

[image: Select the tab control]

- Go to properties, use <kbd>F4</kbd> to do so
- Select **TabPages** property, use <kbd>F4</kbd> to do so
- Click the **<kbd>...</kbd>** after the `(Collection)`.

[image: tab control properties]

- Edit the name and any `tabPage` properties associated with it.

[image: Edit the name and any <code>tabPage</code> properties]

Answer (score 17):

```
tabCtrl.TabPages[0].Text = "some text";
tabCtrl.TabPages[1].Text = "some other text";
```

Answer (score 0):

Going into the **designer.cs** you can change the tab Text like so `this.tabPage3.Text = 'Your Title'`

Method

```
//Component Designer generated code
 private void InitializeComponent()
 {      
  ...
  this.tabControl1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabControl();
  ...
  // 
  // tabPage3
  // 
   this.tabPage3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
   this.tabPage3.Name = "tabPage3";
   ...        
   this.tabPage3.Text = "tabPage3";//change the tab name
   ...
  }
```

It will auto refresh the Design view.